# How to create a custom materialized view that pulls up data from one server to another in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, query-performance, materialized-views

I have 2 databases, the first one called "db1" and the second one called "db2". each one is located on a different server: "server1" and "server2" respectively. However, those 2 servers are connected which means I can query "db2" from "server1".

I have a complicated stored procedures located in "db1" that queries "db2". This stored procedure is complicated and has lots of joins and unions. I was thinking if I can create a materialized view inside "db1" that execute this complicated stored procedure every day at 12:00 AM. so I can query the view directly from "db1" located on "server1" without connecting to "db2" located on "server2".

Again, "server1" and "server2" are linked servers.

Can anyone show me how to create this materialized view?

Thanks!

Comment: Is db1 being replicated from db2 or are they distinctly different databases? Also, how does a view execute a stored procedure on a configured time interval?

Comment: That sounds less like a view, and more like a table. You can do `truncate table; insert into table exec sproc(parameters);`,

Comment: @RossBush db1 is different form db2

Comment: @Blorgbeard is it good every time to truncate the table then insert 30K record? I want the stored procedure to automatically run, let's say, every day at 12am or every 4 hours.. and update the view that I will have in DB1 located on server1

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, assuming it completes in an acceptable time. What do you mean "update the view"? You can't manually update a view (and I don't think you can create a materialized view over tables on a linked server anyway).

Answer (score -1):

One solution would be to create a **Linked Server**. That is, you can create a Linked Server in "Server 1" to "server 2" such that, "Server 2" can be accessed from "Server 1". Then you can create the required view in "Server 2" and access it from "Server 1" similar to accessing any regular view or table.

Then to create a view using the Linked Server, use four part qualified name.
Ex-

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[viewname] 
AS 
    SELECT  * 
    FROM    servername.database.dbo.table 
GO
```

Comment: they are linked as I described in my question "connected".. However, I don't know how to create that view

Comment: Updated the answer describing how to create the view.

Comment: View is nothing but a select statement. It does not store data in any place. So whenever you select from the view, it executes the underling select statement and get the results. If you want to store data to a table, it's a different story. What exactly do you want to do buddy :-). 

Btw, if you want to execute a select statement, you can do it by SQL Server Agent.

If you are happy with my answer, please up-vote it :-).

Comment: I think I want materialized view.. and as I described in my question I want to create a sql-job that runs on the server to update my table

Comment: Materialized views is a concept that is available in Oracle, not in SQL Server. As I have explained in my answer, you can create a view referring a Linked Server. If you require that data to update a table, then write a stored procedure referring the view and schedule it using SQL Server agent... Please explain the down vote to my answer.